input shape of keras cnn seem to change after first epoch
I'm currently trying to set up a simple CNN that sets of images and a corresponding scalar as input with the output being again a single scalar.
I've written a data generator to handle the large images which get loaded only in batches of 4.
I'm using greyscale images of size 512 x 1152 pixels with 73 channels. So basically I have 73 images for one single scalar.
The relevant sections of the data generator look like this:
def __getitem__(self, index):
    """Generates one batch of data."""
    # Get the indices for this batch
    batch_indices = self.indices[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    
    # Load the batch of images from the numpy array file   
    input, target_scalar = self.__load_batch(batch_indices)

    return input, target_scalar
        


def __load_batch(self, batch_indices):
    """Loads a specific batch of images and their target_scalar."""
    # Open the numpy array file each time to load only the needed data       
    array = np.load(self.images_path, mmap_mode='r')
    try:
        # Access only the rows in the array corresponding to batch_indices
        batch_images = array[batch_indices,:,:,:]
    finally:
        array._mmap.close()
            
    # Get the corresponding target_scalar for the batch
    batch_target_scalar = np.array([self.target_scalar[i] for i in batch_indices])

    batch_input_scalar = np.array([self.input_scalar[i] for i in batch_indices])
    
    return (batch_images, batch_input_scalar), batch_target_scalar

The dimensions of one "input" batch then is (4,512,1152,73) and the corresponding input_scalar is of dimension (4,).
The CNN network then itself has the structure:
class ConvModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, image_size, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        activation_function = 'relu'

       
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation=activation_function,data_format='channels_last')
        self.maxpool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation=activation_function)
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense1 = Dense(256, activation=activation_function)
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense2 = Dense(128, activation=activation_function)
        self.dense3 = Dense(1, activation=activation_function)
        self.dense4 = Dense(1, activation=activation_function)

        self.reshape_scalar_input = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,))  # Ensures scalar input has shape (batch_size, 1)
        self.output_layer = Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):

        # Unpack the inputs (image and scalar input)

        image_input = inputs[0]
        scalar_input = inputs[1]
        
        x = self.conv1(image_input)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        y = self.reshape_scalar_input(scalar_input)
        combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, y])
        x = self.dense4(combined)

        return self.output_layer(x)

After instantiating everything, I start the actual training with
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, batch_size=4)

and looking at the ouput, everything works fine for the first epoch:
The image input is of dimension (None, 512, 1152, 73) and the scalar_input has (None,) which seems about right to me.
The first epoch also finishes without any issues.
As soon as the second epoch is about to start, for some reason, the shape of the image_input now is (512,1152,73) and for the scalar_input (512,1152,73) as well with the corresponding error message:
Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (512, 1152, 73)
So for some reason the data sets get screwed up from one epoch to the next. Any ideas on what could happen here?
I tried taking the scalar input out of the model, so having a CNN that works solely on the images. This worked fine. But as soon as I introduced this second input, things get strange.
